# What would cause %5B%5D converts to %5B0%5D?

Tags: php, nginx

When I post link on my website, If the link consists of `%5B%5D` characters it converts to `%5B0%5D` when I click on that link.

if there is multiple occurrence of `%5B%5D` in link, then on the first occurrence it changes to `%5B0%5D`, on second occurrence it changes to `%5B1%5D` and so on, the number between `%5B` and `%5D` increases by 1 everytime it occurs in url.

Also we face this issue when we try to open the posted link via mobile device.

If we open the link on any desktop then nothing adds between `%5B%5D`.

Comment: Can you show us the code for posting the link and for outputting the link?

Comment: So, essentially they're changing to numbered indexes `[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` … at some point? Have you isolated the code path responsible? And how is it a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Some characters are URI encoded before being passed by URL.
If you go to https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and try to decode your %XX you'll find that :

%5B stands for [ and 
%5D stands for ]

So %5B0%5D is the encoded version of [0], %5B1%5D is the encoded version of [1] and so on.

This means you are probably passing some array-like data through your links.

Comment: if I am passing array then it should be applicable on desktop computer as well. But it works perfect on desktop computer. In original link there is no digits between %5B and %5D. that digits are added automatically in mobile device. In mobile device when I click on that link it add 0, 1, 2 and so on between %5B and %5D.